# Google Sheets: Group Values in rows based on duplicate value in column

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am trying to sort Google Sheets data in columns.

**Raw Data**

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]

I know that this can be offered with some time of `QUERY` function but I cannot get it to work exactly how I want. I have already read through [this thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/how-to-group-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet) on Google Sheets and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060378/group-values-in-excel-according-duplicate-value-in-column) on Excel.

Comment: As I said, I've played around with the QUERY function but cannot find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `query` can do exactly this: it can aggregate data in a few ways, but not in the way of "take the values and arrange in a row".  I would use `unique` and `filter` for this purpose. Assuming the input columns are A,B and the output columns are C, D,... the  formulas would be

C2:  `=unique(A2:A)` to return the team numbers without repetition
D2: `=transpose(filter(B2:B, A2:A=C2))` to return the matching scores, transposed to become a row.

The formula in D2 needs to be copied/dragged down the D column.